# Nested resources with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular. In my application, I have two REST resources,

1. To get the User based on the ID
   /users/123
2. To get the buddy details of the user
   users/123/buddies/456

Below is the code I am using,

```
//get the user 
Restangular.one("users", 123).get().then(function(user){
        $scope.user = user;
});
```

Restangular makes a call to /users/123. So far so good.

```
//get the buddy
var getBuddy = function(){
     $scope.user.one("buddies", "456").get();
}
```

But here, Restangular makes the call to /users/buddies/456 instead of /users/123/buddies/456.

I have gone through the samples provided and I can't spot a mistake. Looks like I am overseeing the obvious but this issue has been frustrating me for more than a day now. Does anyone have a hint?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try forming url like this.

```
Restangular.one("users", 123).one("buddies", 456).get().then(function(buddy){
    $scope.buddy = buddy; });
```

or remove double quotes of "456" e.g one("buddies", 456), it should work.

Comment: Thanks. That works but the idea was to use the user object returned by Restanuglar to request for its child resources (buddies). What I was trying to do is used by the creator of Restangular in his presentations (see https://cdn.parleys.com/p/535a189ee4b0c5ba17d43455/rGZ68Mz0Ywz-restangular-devoxx.pdf). But never seems to work for me.

Comment: do something like this var User = function() {return Restangular.one("users", 123).get().then;} and var getBuddy = function(User) {return User.one("buddies", 456).get().then;} use promise returned by function for result.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the Restangular [documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#i-use-mongo-and-the-id-of-the-elements-is-_id-not-id-as-the-default-therefore-requests-are-sent-to-undefined-routes)

If you are using MongoDB, remember to configure the id field.