# Restangular - put and nested get

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, restangular

I'm having the same problem as this unsolved question: [Nested resources with Restangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855472/nested-resources-with-restangular)

Im using the MEAN stack

First I get my club (api/clubs/club_id)

```
Restangular.one('clubs', $routeParams.id).get().then(function (club) {
        $scope.club = club;
});
```

Im following the Restangular documentation and try to do this nested call:

```
$scope.club.getList("contactpersons")
```

But it does not work. I believe my nested call goes to api/clubs/contactperson and not api/clubs/club_id/contactpersons as it should.

I'm also trying to update the club information. like this

```
$scope.saveInfo = function () {
        var newClub = Restangular.copy($scope.club);

        newClub.put();
    };
```

I get an error in my console that says the call goes to api/clubs and not api/clubs/club_id as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Make sure that `$routeParams.id` has the right value. When `Restangular.one` recieves a null or undefined as a second parameter, the URL becomes only the value of the first parameter. In this case, if `$routeParams.id` is null or undefined, the request would point to '/clubs'. It seems that the error that your console is showing is because of that, and its referring to the first request.

Comment: The $routeParams.id works fine. I get all the data from the club, and I can also get the contactperson info if I write: Restangular.one('clubs', $routeParams.id).all('contactpersons').getList().then(function (contactPersons) {
        $scope.contactPersons = contactPersons;
    });

Comment: Another thing i've noticed is that even though the data from the club is there, the object is undefined in console.log. But if get the data with $scope.club = Restangular.one('clubs', $routeParams.id).get().$object; the console.log works. The nested get still dont works though.

Comment: Are you making sure that the first request has finished before making the second request?

Comment: I think so, how would I know?

Comment: Making sure that the call to `$scope.club.getList("contactpersons")` is inside the promise of the previous request (right after `$scope.club = club`), or in a chained promise after that one.

Comment: if i do this:    `Restangular.one('clubs', $routeParams.id).get().then(function (club) {
        $scope.club = club;


    $scope.club.getList("contactpersons").then(function (contactPersons) {
        $scope.contactPersons = contactPersons;
    });

    });` i get an error: Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else

Comment: Restangular expects arraysnas answers when using getList. In the documentation the have an explanation on hoy to handle that.